# Imread installation error ( pip install imread ) : Visual C++ required

Tags: python, deep-learning, imread

When I install Imread on Windows 10 PC I'm getting below error message saying "Microsoft Visual C++ 14 is required"
But it's already installed

[Error on pip install imread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3tqZ.png)

[Visual C++ 14 Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJpTs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#imread) , download the wheel file and install via pip install [file_location]

Answer (score 0):

Check here
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
Unofficial python binaries for windows.  Download the appropriate .whl file and install